# CALayer within UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2, calayer

I am building a menu based upon buttons. I am building them purely in code.

```
let menu00 = UIButton()
menu00.frame=menuHome
let imageSubLayer = CALayer()
imageSubLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "menuIcon.png")!.CGImage
menu00.layer.insertSublayer(drawHexFill(menu00.frame, fillColor: UIColor.lightGrayColor()), atIndex: 2)
menu00.layer.insertSublayer(drawHexBorder(menu00.frame, fillColor: UIColor.clearColor()), atIndex: 1)
menu00.layer.insertSublayer(imageSubLayer, atIndex: 0)
menu00.titleLabel!.text="MENU"
menu00.titleLabel!.textColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
menu00.tag=100
self.view.addSubview(menu00)
```

drawHexFill and drawHexBorder are two UIBezierPath methods to draw the graphical layers, which I do as the button may have different colour border and fill depending on the situation.

The problem I have is that the text and the image are not visible. If I add the image as the button image, it is visible, however behind the hex border and hex fill layers.

I have tried different positions "atIndex" for all objects but simply cannot get what I want. I would like hexFill in the background, hexBorder next and image or text on top.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get this working? If so, consider adding the answer and closing the question, or, if the given answered solved if for your; closingthe question by accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is possibly that your `subLayer`s have different values of their `.zPosition` property. From

> Adds a new sublayer object to the current layer. The sublayer is added
>   to the end of the layer’s list of sublayers. This causes the sublayer
>   to appear on top of any siblings **with the same value in their
>   zPosition property**.

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/BuildingaLayerHierarchy/BuildingaLayerHierarchy.html). You could double-check that the `.zPosition` property has the same value for all your three sublayers.

---

If this is not the issue, try using `insertSubLayer:above` instead of `insertSubLayer:atIndex` (see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/insertSublayer:above:)).